# django api not working from <form> but working in postman

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to download the returned json from the django api. I tested on postman the django api is correctly showing the json, but when i try in my html it's showing

> Error code 501.
>   Message: Can only POST to myapp
>   Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation.

**views.py**:

```
@csrf_exempt
def export_json(request):
    projectname = "resume"
    folderpath = "/home/user/mywebapp/data"
    if request.method == "POST":
        fullpath=os.path.join(folderpath,projectname)
        json_result=ann_json(fullpath)

        with open("json_file.json","w",encoding="utf-8") as jsonfile:
            json.dump(json_result,jsonfile)

        file1 = open("../json_file.json", "r",encoding="utf-8")
        response = HttpResponse(file1.read(),content_type="application/force-download")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement; filename=%s' % smart_str("json_file.json")
        response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str("myapp/project/json_file.json")

        return response
```

**index.html**:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/export_json" method="POST">
    <label class="optinLabel">Project Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="confirm your project name"/>
    <label class="optionLabel">Downlaod</label>
    <input  type="submit" value="Json" style="color:red" />
</form>

<script>
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/export_json')
        .then((response) => return response.json())
        .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("jsonfile",data)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` is set to the `GET` method by default. Looking from your error you are using a different method than `POST` to access your endpoint. Manually set the `method` property correctly in the settings of `fetch`.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/export_json', { method: 'POST' })
  .then((response) => return response.json())
  .then((data) => {
  localStorage.setItem("jsonfile",data)
});
```

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks